# How can I get the uploaded image's width and height in django?

Tags: django, image-upload

How can I get the uploaded image's width and height in django?

Don't use PIL.

Comment: Why would you not allow the use of PIL?  This is exactly what it is for.

Comment: Then use [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow)

Comment: I mean don't use other package, just django. Is there a method or attribution in django to get the upload image width and height as simple as like request.FILES['filename'].name

Answer (score 2):

ImageField will deal with the width and height of the image automatically. You do NOT need to do ANY THING.

1. Change the project setting

Append these code at the end of the setting.py in project directory

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

and then change the urls.py in the project directory

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(...),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

2. Provide two integer fields to store the image's width and height

models.py

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', width_field = 'image_width', height_field='image_height')
    image_width = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    image_height = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

3. Create a Form, DO NOT INCLUDE "image_width" and "image_height", which are supposed to be hidden and filled automatically.

forms.py

```
class PictureForm(forms.Form)
    image = forms.ImageField()
```

4. Validate and process form in view and save the data into database

views.py

```
def createPicture(request):
    form = PictureForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        picture = Picture()
        picture.image = form.cleaned_data['image']
        picture.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('picture-list'))
    else:
        form = PictureForm()
    return render(request, 'template_file', {'form' : form})
```

Answer (score 0):

Delegate to a package specifically for handling images. Such as PIL.

Answer (score 0):

Django has [`ImageField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/fields/#imagefield) which will do this calculation automatically, but you need PIL installed.

Once you have set it up, you'll get `height` and `width` attributes for your images automatically, so you can do this:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
   img = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')

foo = SomeModel.objects.get(pk=1)
print('The height is {0.height} and the width is {0.width}'.format(foo.img))
```